# How to inject HTML before closing html tag in a HTTPModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

I'm trying to inject some additional markup in the response but its not outputting as expected.

For example the following code will output:

```
... </html>CONTENT

private void OnEndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;
    context.Response.Write("CONTENT");
}
```

But i want the content to output right before the closing html tag

```
... CONTENT</html>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: why the choice of HttpModule? Why not extend/override Page? Basically I don't think you will achieve this as easily as you could overriding Page because you will have to make sure your module has been load into the ASP.NET stack AFTER the rendering module, work out if this is a request for your particular 'verb' (see HttpHandler), and then Regex => insert at point. Whereas with Page you could just override the RenderEndTag writing content to HtmlTextWriter before calling base.RenderEndTag...

Comment: Because i don't own the page.  I am writing a plugin which can be used in any asp.net app so its not as simple as overriding the page :)

Comment: @Fixer, have you worked out the problem? I made something similar but I have had problems rewriting the Stream during the EndRequest. Can you post some code to explain how you did? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use an `HttpContext.Response.Filter`.

Check this MSDN documentation page:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx

This very old article should clarify this too:

- http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/10/20/httpfilter.html

Summarizing, you need to create a Stream implementation wrapping the original one coming in `HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter`.

In order to inject HTML in some part of the document, you simply need to convert bytes into a string and using a `String.IndexOf` or a regular expression you're going to deremine if you're in the whole code line.

After that, just concatenate, modify or replace obtained string and put it in the wrapped Stream coming in the original, default response filter.